# Can you query by a range in a GSI in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Suppose I had a users and images tables in DynamoDB.

```
users table
userId (hash) name email 

images table
imagesId (hash) userId filename
```

How should I set up the range or GSI if I wanted to get all images for a single userId? Should images table be a composite key with imageId (hash) and userId (range) and search by range (if possible)? or should userId (be a GSI) and query just be userId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you could [add a GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.OnlineOps.Creating) on your **Images** table with the reverse key schema of your table:

- `hash key - userId`
- `range key - imagesId`
- `filename` - additional property

You can then query this GSI with a `userId` to get all of its associated `imagesId`.

Comment: Just for the record, you can also store the images on the same `users` table as a list of maps. You would save yourself a query and a global index, since you would be able to retrieve the images with just a `GetItem` request (it's also a lot cheaper).

Comment: @MatiasCicero Good call. I was assuming that he already had these as existing tables, which might not be valid. @cdub, another option would be to make use of what @MatiasCicero said and use [`UpdateExpressions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html) to modify the nested maps. Save on the GSI, multiple tables, etc. It is up to you how you want to store and retrieve the data!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot query using just a range key in DynamoDB.

Unless you want your query results from the `images` table to be sorted by `userId`, there's no point to using it as a range key. If you want to retrieve all of the images with a certain `userId` from the images table using a query, you need to use a GSI on `userId`.